# Sharepoint Designer 2010 - Lists and Libraries not showing/populating

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I was wondering if anyone could give me any information regarding the dependencies for this?

I can see the lists just fine within the website.

I can load up the sharepoint admin central site in sharepoint designer and see lists.

Permissions are all turned on but not love.

returns 404 - not sure if required or not.

NEW INFO:

This issue has occurred after updating Sharepoint to 2010.

I setup logging so that I could see if there were any errors and sure enough there were.

"Failed to determine the setup path of the list schema for feature {75a0fea7-040e-4abb-b94b-32f1e7572840}, list template 106.

I think I have to either install this feature or remove the list item that uses it.

EDIT SOLUTION:
So ... this GUID refers to a list item that is using a particular template or something from 40 fab templates.  In upgrading to sharepoint 2010 these no longer worked.

So there were three lists:
Absences
Absence Types
Google Maps .. something.

Deleting these from powershell was the resolution.

A tell tale sign of which items were causing the dramas was that when you clicked on it from within the website it errored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable Sharepoint Designer for the web application:

*Central Admin > Manage Web Applications > (Select the proper app) > General Settings > Sharepoint Designer*

Enable Sharepoint Designer for the site collection:

*Site Actions > Site Settings > Sharepoint Designer Settings > Enable Sharepoint Designer*

Make sure you have "Design" permissions for the site:

*[According to Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2592376), you must be in one of these groups:*

- Site Collection Administrators
- Designers
- Owners

You should reboot or reset IIS after making all of these changes. If this doesn't work, [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) might show you what's going on.

Comment: The sharepoint designer permissions are set correctly in the place you have identified.  I am able to view other parts within the site designer, just not any lists or libraries.

Comment: Please see recent update above.